# How to make full div without using width and height property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">A</div>
</div>
```

My outer is responsive for window size i.e width = 100%, height= 100%.

All i need is to make "inner" as height and width of 100%, but without using width and height property for inner?

```
i.e inner{height: 100%; width : 100%}
```

Even i dont want use js?

Comment: @pirabdulwakeel: Plz read the question carefully.

Comment: You want to tell it to be 100% width and height without telling it which width and height it should have? Why can't you use it?

Comment: any specific reason for not using height and width?

Comment: But the inner div already takes height and width of 100%. See this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cP6jL/

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged the question with `javascript` and `jquery` and say you don't want answers that include them.

Comment: @P5Coder, no it doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/cP6jL/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Using `position` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/9HTSA/

Answer (score 4):

```
.outer{
position:relative;
}

.inner{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7EXG7/)

Comment: Same results `.outer { display: table; } .inner { display: table-cell; }` ;)

Comment: is this what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

On the outer div set `display:table;`

On the inner div set `display: table-cell`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RRGtk/)**

Answer (score 1):

we can do with `position` property

```
.outer{
position:relative;
}
```

link :http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
learn this

Answer (score -1):

you can try below code:

```
<div class="outer" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <div class="inner" style="display: block;height: inherit;">A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the question carefully, he don,t want to you height property.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate: user don't want specific height property like 100%, but inherit specifies that the value of the height property should be inherited from the parent element

Comment: I have same answer but he dont want to use height and width in his code.Check the answer given by other people who dont have height for .inner{}

Answer (score -1):

Visit this Url:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

It uses the float element for the output.